# No highlighting in diamond (moderator) notifications

Tags: bug, design, notifications, moderator-tools

Moderators just got notifications for four new feature changes.  Here's what mine looked like:

[image: screen shot]

Note the diamond's orange hue, which tells us that at least one of these is a new notification.  You'll have to take my word for it that they were all new and that I didn't read some of them in that 3-second window.

Usually new entries in this list, like those in the achievements and inbox lists, are shaded light blue to convey their newness.  That was certainly true as recently as the arrival of the next item down in this list.  This shading did not happen this time.  Another moderator reported that one of his was blue but the others were not.

I don't know if it matters that these notifications were generated by blog updates.

This is a minor bug, but I was asked to report it here anyway so here you go.

Comment: Reporting a second data point, myself as the person who made the announcements, when I submitted them all, I only had it highlight the latest of the announcements (and failed to consider screenshotting). So there's definitely something funky - it may be because of the fact so many announcements were made consecutively.

Comment: I experienced this too, so definitely real.