# What is the meaning of the different diamond colors shown to moderators in the top bar?

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-tools, top-bar

Some moderators have been talking about things like "orange diamond events" but I couldn't find a good reference on Meta for what that means. So I must ask: What diamond? What colors are there and what do they mean?

Comment: I don't think I've seen moderators talk like this, and I thought I was pretty well plugged in to SE meta. It's neat to have this kind of transparency, though.

Comment: Fun fact. I call the orange diamond the batsignal. No one else does (I think?) but its almost universally understood :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### What is the diamond for?

On the top bar, moderators have a diamond icon which functions as an inbox for certain events. Each site has its own diamond inbox, so as a moderator on three sites, I have access to three different ones (per site metas share the same messages as their parent site, but the "dashboard" link is different). In much the same way that the universal "achievements" dropdown has links to privileges and badges, the diamond has links to "Mod Team Q&A" (our space on [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflowteams.com/)) and "dashboard" (which links to `/admin` which shows moderator activity and some other tabs to useful stuff).

### Default diamond

The diamond is grey (matching the other top bar icons) when there aren't any new messages since the last time the moderator looked. Here is an image showing where it is on the top bar (note that the blue number next to it is flags, which disappears when there are none):

[image: Top bar: diamond, flags, user card, inbox, trophy, review, help, site switcher]

As a bonus, here's what it looks like with the light top bar that's only available on Stack Overflow (including the international sites):

[image: slightly darker grey]

### Blue diamond

[image: new meta question, followed by the title of the meta question]

Any number of routine site-specific events will trigger it:

- New questions on the site's per-site meta (not issued on Stack Overflow or sites without a per-site meta, i.e., Meta.SE and Stack Apps)
- Moderator messages / Moderator message replies (if you're the mod who started the thread, you also get notified in your regular inbox)
- Community team messages (the title "community team message" is used for all replies to CM escalations, no matter if they come from CMs or mods)

### Orange diamond

[image: announcement Stack Moderators Team post]

The orange diamond is exclusively for announcements. This is a completely manual process, so each notification has a title and a link hand-picked by a staff member. The link can lead anywhere, but most often it's to a question on the mod team. It's also possible for an orange notification to be deleted (again, by staff).

These are uncommon (but may have been more common in the past). Some months don't even have any announcements, though since the end of May we've had a total of 7 (some of which was related to matters pertaining to the strike). Examples of announcements include:

- New mod-specific tools
- New policies
- Important discussions
- Surveys
- Reminders for virtual meet ups

Comment: "*These are uncommon (but may have been more common in the past).*" - They're much more common now than they were in the past. Mods could serve for several years and never see an orange diamond.

Comment: @Mithical That's based on something I heard on the mod team, but I'm not sure what time frame it's based on. If we go back nearly a decade, [this 2014 bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239598/323179) shows that some announcements came only 3 to 7 seconds after each other (probably doesn't extrapolate though).