# Add a link to the site cookie settings from the User Settings page

Tags: feature-request, cookies, preferences, cookie-consent-dialog

Apparently cookie settings are configurable via a link on the site footer. I found this out thanks to a brief mention on the [Advertising Guidelines update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395389/179041):

> **Opt in or out of cookie tracking**
>
> To opt in or out of cookie tracking, scroll down all the way to the bottom of any page on Stack Overflow or a Stack Exchange Site. Under the “Company” heading click “Cookie Settings”. There you can change your cookie preferences.

This isn't where I'd have expected these settings to be - I don't often have a reason to view/check the footer.

It would be nice if there was a way for logged in users to configure them from the [User settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395389/179041) page - even just a link that opens the same modal that the footer shows would suffice.

---

I originally raised this on the aforementioned Ad Guidelines Update meta, but it was [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395389/update-to-our-advertising-guidelines/395434?noredirect=1#comment1322852_395434) to break this into it's own feature request.

Comment: Does the footer link even work? I get «We couldn’t save your cookie preferences. Please adjust your browser settings or disable ad blocking. You can access your cookie settings at any time by clicking “Cookie Settings” in the footer.» This is like IAB's preposterous stance that people need to enable cookies from hundreds of partners in order to opt out from cookies.

Comment: It does for me @Nemo - but it's a [OneTrust](https://www.onetrust.com/cookie-banner-gallery/) banner/popover box. If you have any plugins or adblocker rules that also block popovers (Social blockers, I Don't Care about Cookies etc) they could be interfering with it.

Comment: that's my point, you need to enable ads in order to disable ads.

Comment: @Nemo I'm not sure I understand your point - you asked if the footer link works - it does. If you can't access it but want to, you'll need to track down the interfering adblock filter/rule or browser plugin and explicitly allow the popup (perhaps only for SE sites, and only for as long as it takes for you to configure your cookie settings, if that's what you prefer). Otherwise you can use [a browser](https://spreadprivacy.com/introducing-duckduckgo-for-mac) or plugin that auto sets cookies to the minimum required automatically. Neither requires you to "enable ads" :)